# Reference to address in data section wrong after assembly and linking

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm, mach-o

I have this assembly program (test.asm):

```
global main
extern _printf

section .text
main:
  push  rbp
  mov   rdi, message2
  call  _printf
  pop   rbp
  ret

section .data
message1: db "foo", 10, 0
message2: db "bar", 10, 0
```

My problem is that it doesn't print anything. If I use message1 it works, just not with message2. What am I doing wrong?

When I look at the final executable, it seems that the address in the MOV instruction points to the address **right after** the message2 string. There are just null bytes there. In test.o the address points to two bytes **before** the proper start of the string.

I assemble and link it like this:

```
nasm -f macho64 -o test.o test.asm
ld -arch x86_64 -macos_version_min 10.14 -no_pie -lSystem -e main -o test test.o
```

I'm using NASM 2.13.03. I'm on macOS 10.14.6 on a MacBook Pro with an Intel(R) Core(TM) i9-9880H CPU @ 2.30GHz.

---

Ghidra output for test.o:

```
                     //
                     // __text 
                     // __TEXT
                     // ram: 00000000-00000011
                     //
                     undefined main()
     undefined         AL:1           <RETURN>
                     main
00000000 55              PUSH       RBP
00000001 48 bf 17        MOV        RDI,0x17
         00 00 00 
         00 00 00 00
0000000b e8 f0 0f        CALL       _printf
         00 00
00000010 5d              POP        RBP
00000011 c3              RET
                     //
                     // __data 
                     // __DATA
                     // ram: 00000012-0000001b
                     //
                     message1
00000012 00              ??         00h
00000013 00              ??         00h
00000014 66              ??         66h    f
00000015 6f              ??         6Fh    o
00000016 6f              ??         6Fh    o
                     message2
00000017 0a              ??         0Ah
00000018 00              ??         00h
00000019 62              ??         62h    b
0000001a 61              ??         61h    a
0000001b 72              ??         72h    r
                     //
                     //  
                     // ram: 0000001c-0000001d
                     //
0000001c 0a              ??         0Ah
0000001d 00              ??         00h
[snip]
```

And for the final executable:

```
[snip]
                      //
                      // __text 
                      // __TEXT
                      // ram: 100000f84-100000f95
                      //
                      undefined entry()
      undefined         AL:1           <RETURN>
                      main
                      entry
100000f84 55              PUSH       RBP
100000f85 48 bf 22        MOV        RDI=>DAT_100001022,DAT_100001022
          10 00 00 
          01 00 00 00
100000f8f e8 02 00        CALL       __stubs::_printf
          00 00
100000f94 5d              POP        RBP
100000f95 c3              RET
[snip]
                      //
                      // __data 
                      // __DATA
                      // ram: 100001018-100001021
                      //
                      message1
100001018 66              ??         66h    f
100001019 6f              ??         6Fh    o
10000101a 6f              ??         6Fh    o
10000101b 0a              ??         0Ah
10000101c 00              ??         00h
                      message2
10000101d 62              ??         62h    b
10000101e 61              ??         61h    a
10000101f 72              ??         72h    r
100001020 0a              ??         0Ah
100001021 00              ??         00h
                      //
                      // __DATA 
                      // __DATA
                      // ram: 100001022-100001fff
                      //
                      DAT_100001022
100001022 00              ??         00h
100001023 00              ??         00h
100001024 00              ??         00h
[snip]
```

Comment: Post proof of your claim, such as disassembly of the relevant part of the executable along with the strings. PS: you should zero `al` before calling `printf`.

Comment: I added what Ghidra shows me. I hope that will do. Why do I need to zero `al`?

Comment: Because the calling convention says it should contain the number of SSE registers used for passing arguments to varargs functions (and `printf` is one). But that's unrelated to your problem which is interesting. Does it work if you use `lea rdi, [rel message2]` ?

Comment: @Jester: this smells like one of the known bugs with NASM's mach-o output format.  IIRC, the more recent one affects 64-bit absolute instead of RIP-relative.

Comment: Ah yeah I keep forgetting about that bug.

Comment: `lea rdi, [rel message2]` works! Thank you.